# how to replace a text on XML with lxml?

Tags: python-2.7, xml-parsing, lxml

I'm trying to troncate several element.text on a xml file. I succeed to get two list, the first one regroup the formers too long element.text as str (long_name) and the second regroup the same after a troncation (short_name).

Now i want to replace the element.text on my xml, i tried some script but i surrended to work with the function readlines(), i want to find a similar solution with lxml as this code :

```
txt = open('IF_Generic.arxml','r')
Lines = txt.readlines()
txt.close()

txt = open('IF_Genericnew.arxml','w')

for e in range(len(long_name)) :
    for i in range(len(Lines)) :
        if (long_name[e] in Lines[i]) == True :
            Lines[i] = Lines[i].replace(long_name[e],short_name[e])

for i in Lines :
     txt.write(i)

txt.close()
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work :

```
f = open('IF_Generic.arxml')
arxml = f.read()
f.close()
tree = etree.parse(StringIO(arxml))
for e,b in enumerate(long_name) :
    context = etree.iterparse(StringIO(arxml))
    for a,i in context:
        if not i.text:
            pass
        else:
            if (b in i.text) == True :
                i.text = short_name[e]

obj_arxml = etree.tostring(tree,pretty_print=True)

f = open('IF_Genericnew.arxml','w')
f.write(obj_arxml)
f.close()
```

Let's say the first element of the list long_name is RoutineServices_EngMGslLim_NVMID03

```
<BALISE_A>
    <BALISE_B>
        <SHORT-NAME>RoutineServices_EngMGslLim_NVMID03</SHORT-NAME>
    </BALISE_B>
</BALISE_A>
<BALISE_C>
    <POSSIBLE-ERROR-REF DEST="APPLICATION-ERROR">/Interfaces/RoutineServices_EngMGslLim_NVMID03/E_NOT_OK</POSSIBLE-ERROR-REF>
    <SHORT-NAME>Blah_Bleh_Bluh</SHORT-NAME>
</BALISE_C>
```

The first element of the list short_name is RoutineServices_EngMGslLim_NV

```
<BALISE_A>
    <BALISE_B>
        <SHORT-NAME>RoutineServices_EngMGslLim_NV</SHORT-NAME>
    </BALISE_B>
</BALISE_A>
<BALISE_C>
    <POSSIBLE-ERROR-REF DEST="APPLICATION-ERROR">/Interfaces/RoutineServices_EngMGslLim_NV/E_NOT_OK</POSSIBLE-ERROR-REF>
    <SHORT-NAME>Blah_Bleh_Bluh</SHORT-NAME>
</BALISE_C>
```

I want this

P.S: I use python 2.7.9

Thanks in advance everyone !

Comment: @mzjn To simplify, we will say that i have 2 lists, i want to browse all the element.text in my xml and replace it. The list long_name is the criteria to know if i have to replace the text or not and the list short_name is the new text i want to put. I can't give you the xml file because it's like 500k lines.

Comment: @mzjn i tried to be as minimal as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't open XML files like text files.** I have [explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44442488/18771) why this is a bad idea.

Simply let `etree` read and write the file. It's also less code to write.

```
from lxml import etree

# read the file and load it into a DOM tree
tree = etree.parse('IF_Generic.arxml')


for elem in tree.iterfind("//*"):
    # find elements that contain only text
    if len(elem) == 0 and elem.text and elem.text.strip() > '':
        # do your replacements ...
        elem.text = "new text"


# serialize the DOM tree and write it to file
tree.write('IF_Genericnew.arxml', pretty_print=True)
```

Instead of going over *all* elements, which is what `"//*"` does, you can use more specific XPath to narrow down the elements you want to work on.

For example, something like `"//SHORT-NAME | //POSSIBLE-ERROR-REF"` would help to reduce the overall work load.

Comment: i'm trying your solution but i got this error for the "serialize and write the file" part : 'module' object has no attribute 'write' something is missing ?
I have to check all elements so i can't specify Xpath.

Comment: Whoops, typo. I typed `etree.write(...)` but of course I meant `tree.write(...)`. This is fixed.

Comment: that's what i thought ! I'm testing it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved me !

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! :)

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._Element' object has no attribute 'write'`

Comment: @not2qubit Don't try to write the `root` element. Write the `tree`.